# Spring Boot parse JSON data to Java Class with different field names

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

I am new to Spring Boot and I am trying to figure out how to parse json data.  I see a lot of tutorials on how to map json string object to an annotated Java class and using and object mapper, like this:

**json:**

```
{
    "UUID": "xyz",
    "name": "some name"
}

public class MyClass{ 
    @JsonProperty 
    private UUID id;
    @JsonProperty
    private String name;

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public UUID getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @JsonAnyGetter
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}   

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyClass customer = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, MyClass.class);
```

The problem is that the system I am getting the json string from does not match the class naming conventions we use (and I cannot change either one).  So, instead of having the example json string above, it might look like this:

```
 {
    "randomdstring-fieldId": "xyz",
    "anotherrandomstring-name": "some name"
}
```

This use case only has two fields, but my use case has a larger payload.  Is there a way to either map the field names from the json object to the field names in the Java class or is there a way to just parse the json string as a key value pair (so that I can just manually add the fields to my Java object)?

Comment: `@JsonProperty(value = "UUID")` -> `Defines name of the logical property, i.e. JSON object fieldname to use for the property. If value is empty String (which is thedefault), will try to use name of the field that is annotated.Note that there is no default name available for constructor arguments,meaning that Empty String is not a valid value for constructor arguments.`

Comment: Thanks!  I will try that!  if you add this as an answer, I will upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jackson with `@JsonProperty` you can customize the field name with it's annotation parameter `value`

Therefore, you just have to annotate the entity fields with the `@JsonProperty` annotation and provide a custom JSON property name, like this:

```
public class MyClass{ 
    @JsonProperty("original_field_name_in_json") 
    private UUID id;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The @JsonProperty will do it for you:

```
@JsonProperty("name_in_json") 
private Long value;
```